# SQL - Agrupar informações e Não permitir repetir

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou fazendo um SQL onde preciso mostrar as ordem de compras.
Porém uma ordem de compra, pode ter várias cotações e não desejo ficar repetindo as cotações, quero que me traga a cotação apenas uma vez sem ficar repetindo.

```
[![select c.Empresa, p.Nome, 
c.data,c.NumeroOC, c.fornecedor, pe.nome, 
(Convert(Numeric(10,2), c.valor)) as 'Valor',
det.descricao as 'Local de Entrega',l.Descricao as 'CR',
Case when c.situacao = 1 then
    'Pendente'
    when c.situacao = 2 then
    'Atendida Parcialmente'
    when c.situacao = 3 then
    'Atendida Totalmente'
    when c.situacao = 4 then
    'Finalizada Manualmente' end as 'Status',
c.ordemaut, 
ic.Cotacao,
c.Obs
from compras c
inner join pessoas p on (c.empresa = p.codigo)
inner join pessoas pe on (c.fornecedor = pe.codigo)
inner join locais l on (c.cresultado = l.codigo) and tipolocal = 'CR'
inner join detpessoas det on (det.Sequencial = c.LocalEntrega)
inner join itenscompra ic on (c.SequencialOC = ic.SequencialOC)][1]][1]
```

Comment: E qual das cotações existentes você gostaria que fosse exibida? Creio que a cláusula GROUP BY e uma função de agregação (MAX por exemplo) possa ajuda-lo.

Comment: Apenas não desejo ver repetidas. Se uma ORDEM DE COMPRA teve 2 cotações, quero ver as dudas, mas não quero ver elas repetidas.

Comment: Defina melhor o que quer dizer com "repetições" já que, pelo que entendi, você deseja ver tais repetições.

Comment: Postei uma foto também. O número da oc e as cotações são as mesmas e desejo agrupar elas.
Até tentei fazer um group by, mas o banco me pede para agrupar campo por campo, o que fica inviável na consulta.

Comment: Imagens anexadas não são bem-vindas neste site. Veja: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Answer (score 1):

se entendi a pergunta

tente usar o "select distinct c.Empresa, p.Nome,
c.data,c.NumeroOC, c.fornecedor, pe.nome from

evita repetições.

Comment: Resolvido! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Se você faz INNER JOIN de um conjunto de tabelas e os dados vem repetidos então muito provavelmente seu banco de dados tem sérios problemas de projeto.